# Xamarin Forms: how to create a facebook login native experience

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

in xamarin forms i want implement a native facebook login.

I've read the following guide: [XamarinFormsNativeFacebook](https://github.com/IdoTene/XamarinFormsNativeFacebook) but it doesn't work with the latest xamarin forms.

There is any tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you go through this [**link**](https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/MVP-Windows-Dev/Login-with-Facebook-in-Xamarin-Forms) and [**this**](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/31928/xamarin-forms-facebook-login-native-login-page-android) for implementing a **Facebook Login**. ***Cheers!***